# DotNetCore SignalR as standalone client

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

This seems like a too simple question, but I could not find this anywhere.

I am building a ASP.Net Core web application and I need to connect to an existing WebSocket on an external non SignalR server. Can SignalR be used as a standalone client. Is it compatible with plain WebSockets, or does it only work / make sense if both the server and client use SignalR?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you’d like to use SignalR clients to communicate with non-SignalR server? As far as I know, SignalR client side will define some client functions and connect to hub, and we could call client functions to broadcast message to all clients in hub method. non-SignalR server could not call these SignalR client side functions.

Best Regards,